# Mac Laptop WiFi Issues with Avaya AP's in a business

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I've been having a definite repeatable problem with MacBook Air's and Pro's using Wifi throughout our building. The WiFi AP's are Avaya Extreme devices attaching to an Avaya switch which then connects to a Cisco switch.

The Mac laptops will come into the office or wake up from sleep and not connect to the internet. If they connect to a different wifi and then back to the main wifi. Then they can connect to the internet okay. This just appears to be an issue with the Mac laptops. Windows laptops are not having that problem ever.

The other issue is the speed in the back of the building is way down sometimes. Maybe 5 or 10 Down and 50 or 60 Up. If we reboot the Avaya switch, then all goes back to normal speeds. I think something is wrong if we constantly have to reboot the Avaya switch every week or two. Our building is offices in front and warehouse type in back.

Does anyone have any clues?